# Finding the sum of column values from a table and displaying them

Tags: reactjs

Say I have a table that stores items and their weights and I want to sum the total weight from that column and display that at the top on the table. Not using anything other than react/jsx. For more clarification, my table is pulling data stored on a node.js/express server.

I tried writing a function to go into my table component that used reduce, it did not work at all and I'm not sure how to go about it at this point.

Would like the total weight to be displayed next to the table header.

Comment: Can you include the code that renders your table? This is possible in a variety of ways, but I will answer in the context of your own code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const GearTable = (props) => {
    return(
        <div style={styles.box}>
            <h3>Your Gear Locker</h3>
            <br />
            <br />
            <Table hover style={[styles.font, styles.box]}>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Item Name</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Weight</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {props.gear.map((gear, id) => {
                        return(
                            <tr key={id}>
                                <th scope="row" style={styles.font}>                                      {gear.id}</th>
                                <td style={styles.font}>                                                  {gear.itemName}</td>
                                <td style={styles.font}>                                                  {gear.description}</td>
                                <td style={styles.font}>                                                  {gear.weight.value}</td>
                                <td style={styles.font}>                                                  {gear.quantity}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <Button className="btn btn-secondary" size="lg" style={styles.font} id={gear.id} onClick={e => props.update(e, gear)}>Update Locker</Button>
                                    <Button className="btn btn-secondary" size="lg" style={styles.font} id={gear.id} onClick={props.delete}>Delete Item</Button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </div>    
    );
}
```

const GearTable = (props) => {
    return(

#### Your Gear Locker

ID
                        Item Name
                        Description
                        Weight
                        Quantity
                    
                
                
                    {props.gear.map((gear, id) => {
                        return(
                            
                                {gear.id}
                                {gear.itemName}
                                {gear.description}
                                {gear.weight.value}
                                {gear.quantity}
                                
                                     props.update(e, gear)}>Update Locker
                                    Delete Item
                                
                            
                            )
                        })
                    }
                
            
        
    );
}

Comment: @Matt, hope this is helps. I can include other bits as well, or a link to my repo